# Why are the Fourier transforms of autocorrelation and cross-correlation different?

Tags: power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I'm almost definitely misunderstanding this, but as far as I can tell we can equate the Fourier transform of the auto-correlation function $R_{xx}(\tau)$ with power spectral density (PSD) like so:

$\hat{R}(\omega) = S_{xx}(\omega) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \textbf{E}[|\hat{x}(\omega)|^{2}]$

Whereas the Fourier transform of the cross correlation is just the complex product of the two functions in frequency space:

$\mathcal{F}\{x(t)∗y(t)\}=\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}\mathcal{F}\{y(t)\}^{*} $

Why does the expected value/mean come into play with the auto-correlation/PSD?

Comment: There  _is_ a notion of **crosscorrelation** function of two jointly wide-sense-stationary processes and its Fourier transform is called the cross-power spectral density. These notions bring in the expectations that you expect to find.

Comment: @DilipSarwate What is the difference between that concept and the cross-correlation cited here?

Comment: @Petra your statement "Is just the product of two functions" is the answer here: you're confusing a property of a stochastic process (the PSD) with something that you apply to a deterministic (because observed) signal. Can't generally do that, so "the cross-correlation is just the product of two functions" is wrong, IMHO.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand (sorry!! my knowledge of signal processing is fairly shaky haha). Does it not follow from the convolution theorem that the Fourier transform of a cross-correlation is the complex product of the Fourier transforms of the functions?

Comment: no, since the (strictly speaking) cross-correlation is a property of two random processes, not of deterministic functions; in this situation it's good to remember that you can make a difference between *sample correlation*, which you calculate on two actual signals that you have, and *correlation*, which is an expectation of two random processes with an infinite amount of realizations (of which you can only observe a finite amount, if at all)

Comment: Is it incorrect, then, to cross-correlate two signals by multiplying them in the frequency domain?

Comment: again, that is the thing you do when you want a **sample** crosscorrelation. That only happens to sometimes coincide with the crosscorrelation for *stochastic processes*: What you do is not right or wrong, it's just a different thing

Comment: Ah, so then the two definitions above are used differently. Do you know how I might adapt the auto-correlation/PSD to be used for a sample correlation in the same way?